# Introduction to Zeraim

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, rambam, mishna

I'm interested in learning the fundamentals of zeraim, and am looking for a good way to familiarize myself with the concepts.

I've seen the Rambam's hakdama to the seder, but it's a little longer than I'm looking for.

Anyone have any recommendations on introductions to the isodos of the seder that are relatively short and easy to learn? (something like the first perek of kelim is to tahoros, but for zeraim).

Many thanks.

Comment: Don't the Artscroll mishnayot contain an introduction in each volume? For the gemara they usually have a very good overview.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the Time4Mishna site which methodically goes through all the mishnayos in shas with a full range of overviews and key terms etc.

So for example in Zeraim, if you look at Mishna Berachos [here](http://time4torah.org/masechta/brachos/), you will note:

1. An [overview](http://time4torah.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Brachos-Overview.pdf)
2. [Key Terms](http://time4torah.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Brachos-Key-terms.pdf)
3. and a [summary](http://time4torah.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Brachos-Summaries.pdf)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion -- I looked at the website and it seems quite informational! i should have probably put this in my above question, but I'm looking for something a little more in-depth. Something that will cover not just the key-words and fundamentals, but explain the main dinim and essentials of the seder. Maybe i'm just being too picky! Anyways, thank you very much for your suggestion -- I will certainly give this website a closer look! many thanks.

Comment: Okay! Wishing you much hatzlocho! :-)